# PostgreSQL - WHERE condition which refers to 2 different records and should be TRUE

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I have tables:

**company_employees:**

```
id_employee
id_company
```

**employees:**

```
id_employee
name
```

**companies:**

```
id_company
name
```

If I execute such as query:

```
SELECT companies.name AS Company, employees.name AS Employee FROM employees
INNER JOIN company_employees ON company_employees.id_employee = employees.id_employee
INNER JOIN companies ON companies.id_company = company_employees.id_company
```

It displays:

```
+-----------+--------------+
|  Company  |   Employee   |
+-----------+--------------+
| Microsoft | John Smith   |
| Microsoft | Mike Brown   |
| IBM       | Chris Miller |
+-----------+--------------+
```

I want to display only company names (**companies.name)** where work employees both 'John Smith' and 'Mike Brown'. So the query should display:

```
+-----------+
|   name    |
+-----------+
| Microsoft |
+-----------+
```

Do you have any idea how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try aggregating by company name, and then asserting that:

- The only two names in each company group are 'John Smith' and 'Mike Brown'
- The number of distinct names in each company group is two

Both of these conditions would imply that any company in the result set matches your criteria.

```
SELECT
    c.name AS Company
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN company_employees ce
    ON ce.id_employee = ee.id_employee
INNER JOIN companies c
    ON c.id_company = ce.id_company
WHERE
    e.name IN ('John Smith', 'Mike Brown')
GROUP BY
    c.name
HAVING
    MIN(e.name) <> MAX(e.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below if 2different employee work on same company below will work

```
SELECT
    c.name AS Company
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN company_employees ce
    ON ce.id_employee = e.id_employee
INNER JOIN companies c
    ON c.id_company = ce.id_company

GROUP BY
    c.name
    HAVING
    count(distinct e.name)=2
```

[DEMO in fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=c7b0ff5a123686cdafbf2c812c951346)

```
company
Microsoft
```